# Rowmeans for N sequential columns

Tags: r, dataframe

In a dataframe with `n*3` columns, how to calculate row means for every three (or any other number) sequential columns, e.g. for columns `(1,2,3)`, `(4,5,6)`, `(7,8,9)`, etc?

There is a solution [here on Code Review-Mean of many subsets of a dataframe](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/58523/mean-of-many-subsets-of-a-dataframe), but I wonder if there is a more elegant method.

Comment: `t(rowsum(t(dat), as.integer(gl(ncol(dat), 3, ncol(dat)))))/3`

Comment: Or `sapply(split.default(dat, rep(seq_along(dat), each=3, length.out=ncol(dat))), rowMeans)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following. This example is based on the data-set provided in the linked question and for every two consecutive columns.

```
dat <- data.frame(a1 = 9:11, a2 = 2:4, b1 = 3:5,
              b2 = 4:6, c1 = 5:7, c2 = 1:3)

n <- 2
t(rowsum(t(dat), as.integer(gl(ncol(dat), n, ncol(dat))))) / n

##        1   2 3
## [1,] 5.5 3.5 3
## [2,] 6.5 4.5 4
## [3,] 7.5 5.5 5
```

Comment: @Hrant It produces factors. Read about it `?gl`.

Answer (score 2):

Base R solution (specify by how many columns to apply function and iterate over those groups):

```
# Generate dummy data (matrix 2 x 9)
foo <- matrix(rnorm(18), 2)
# By how many columns apply function
BY <- 3
# Apply rowmeans by rows and columns
sapply(1:(ncol(foo)/BY), function(x) rowMeans(foo[, ((x * BY) - BY + 1):(x * BY)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way without a loop.

1. The matrix is transformed into an array.
2. The array is transposed with `aperm()` to allow...
3. `colMeans()` to return the intended output. `colMeans()` deals with dimension differently than `rowMeans()` and the transposition provides the intended output.

```r
df<-matrix(1:30, nrow = 3, ncol = 6)

ncols <- 2

colMeans(
  aperm(
    array(df, dim = c(3, ncols, ncol(df) / ncols)),
    perm = c(2,1,3)
    )
  )
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]  2.5  8.5 14.5
#> [2,]  3.5  9.5 15.5
#> [3,]  4.5 10.5 16.5
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

This is the fastest of the three methods:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 13
  expression       min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc
  <bch:expr>    <bch:> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>
1 aperm_method  33.4us 35.1us    27291.        0B
2 rowsum_method 55.6us 57.8us    16854.        0B
3 sapply_method 93.8us 96.9us    10210.    46.5KB
```

Raw code:

```
bench::mark(
  aperm_method = {
    ncols <- 2
    colMeans(
      aperm(
        array(df, dim = c(nrow(df), ncols, ncol(df) / ncols)),
        perm = c(2,1,3)
      )
    )
  }
  ,
  rowsum_method = {
    n <- 2; 
    t(rowsum(t(df), as.integer(gl(ncol(df), n, ncol(df))))) / n
  }
  , 
  sapply_method = {
    BY = 2
    sapply(1:(ncol(df)/BY), function(x) rowMeans(df[, ((x * BY) - BY + 1):(x * BY)]))
  }
  ,
  check = F #all the same except rowsum_method has colnames
)
```